# Perl Curses::UI

Tags: perl, user-interface, curses

I am trying to use the library Curses:UI from http://search.cpan.org/dist/Curses-UI/
to build a UI on linux karmic.

I can create a simple user interface e.g.:

```
#!usr/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Curses;
use Curses::UI;

$ui = new Curses::UI(-color_support=>1,-clear_on_exit=>1,-intellidraw=>1);
my $window = $ui->add('window', 'Window',-intellidraw=>1);
my $message = $window->add(-text=>"Hello!",-intellidraw=>1);
$window->focus(); 
$ui->mainloop();
```

Question: I need some way to  communicate informatio to the UI i.e. I have a loop which will wait for message to come and change the text in window. Once this message comes a popup will be displayed.
Attempt:

```
my $ui = new Curses::UI(-color_support=>1,-clear_on_exit=>1,-intellidraw=>1);
my $window = $ui->add('window', 'Window',-intellidraw=>1);
my $message = $window->add(-text=>"Hello!",-intellidraw=>1);

pseudocode
while(true) #implemented a function to wait
{
    popup($window->text("Hello how are you?"));
}

$window->focus(); 
$ui->mainloop();
```

Problem: The above does not work. I am given a dark screen where my message is displayed. I have read the documentation and when I relocate : $ui->mainloop() above the while loop I am given the user interface but now nothing communicates to the window.

Coincise Question: I need some way of displaying the user interface wait for inputs and display messages.

Could anyone please help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: Must you use Curses?  [Wx Widgets](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Wx) is currently the most actively maintained GUI toolkit for Perl.

Answer (score 4):

I would just replace $ui->mainloop() with my own eventloop where my own stuff is updated aswell.

For reference $ui->mainloop() is implemented as follows:

```
sub mainloop {
    my ($self) = @_;

    # Draw the initial screen.
    $self->focus(undef, 1); # 1 = forced focus
    $self->draw;
    doupdate();

    # Inifinite event loop.
    while (1) { $self->do_one_event }
}
```

So I would simply add your own tick() function to the while loop.