# Show bash script output in live on perl - curses script

Tags: perl, bash, output, curses

I'm a newb' on Perl, and try to do a simple script's launcher in Perl with Curses (Curses::UI)

On Stackoverflow I found a solution to print (in Perl) in real time the output of a Bash script.

But I can't do this with my Curses script, to write this output in a TextEditor field.

For example, the Perl script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Curses::UI;
use Curses::Widgets;
use IO::Select;

my $cui = new Curses::UI( -color_support => 1 );

[...]

my $process_tracking = $container_middle_right->add(
    "text", "TextEditor",
    -readonly       => 1,
    -text           =>  "",
);

sub launch_and_read()
{
    my $s = IO::Select->new();
    open my $fh, '-|', './test.sh';
    $s->add($fh);

    while (my @readers = $s->can_read()) {
        for my $fh (@readers) {
            if (eof $fh) {
                $s->remove($fh);
                next;
            }
            my $l = <$fh>;
            $process_tracking->text( $l );
            my $actual_text = $process_tracking->text() . "\n";
            my $new_text = $actual_text . $l;
            $process_tracking->text( $new_text );
            $process_tracking->cursor_to_end();
        }
    }
}

[...]

$cui->mainloop();
```

This script contains a button to launch launch_and_read().

And the test.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( seq 1 5 )
do
    sleep 1
    echo "from $$ : $( date )"
done
```

The result is my application freeze while the bash script is executed, and the final output is wrote on my TextEditor field at the end.

Is there a solution to show in real time what's happened in the Shell script, without blocking the Perl script ?

Many thanks, and sorry if this question seems to be stupid :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't block. Curses's loop needs to run to process events. So you must poll. `select` with a timeout of zero can be used to poll.

```
my $sel;

sub launch_child {
   $sel = IO::Select->new();
   open my $fh, '-|', './test.sh';
   $sel->add($fh);
}

sub read_from_child {
   if (my @readers = $sel->can_read(0)) {
      for my $fh (@readers) {
         my $rv = sysread($fh, my $buf, 64*1024);
         if (!$rv) {
            $sel->remove($fh);
            close($fh);
            next;
         }

         ... add contents of $buf to the ui here ...
      }
   }
}

launch_child();
$cui->set_timer(read_from_child => \&read_from_child, 1);
$cui->mainloop();
```

Untested.

Note that I switched from `readline` (`<>`) to `sysread` since the former blocks until a newline is received. Using blocking calls like `read` or `readline` defies the point of using `select`. Furthermore, using buffering calls like `read` or `readline` can cause `select` to say nothing is waiting when there actually is. Never use `read` and `readline` with `select`.

Comment: I just changed `if ($sel->can_read(0)) {` by `if (my @readers = $sel->can_read(0)) {`, and it's almost work ; I have to do something (press a key, change list selection) to refresh the TextEditor. Curses doesn't refresh if I don't do anything ?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment : Curses seems to launch mainloop each time it receives an input ; now my problem is, how to run mainloop permanently without waiting any user input...

Comment: The problem is (roughly speaking) that it only calls callbacks after processing another event. Replaced the callback with a timer. That should solve that problem. It'll poll the child every second, the smallest period supported.

Comment: Works like a charm :) I'll try, just to see if it can works, a solution like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931951/perl-cursesui#answer-4944590 (maybe more frequently than 1 seconds to update ^^)

Comment: I think you'd be better off using `package Curses::UI; use Time::HiRes qw( time );` before `use Curses::UI;`, and use `0.1` instead of `1`.